# Java Script Date Function

Tags: javascript

Below JS to get current time does not return any value. I am calling the ecmascript function from my jsp page.

```
function abc{   
    var returnString = '';
    var today = new Date();
    var currentTime = today.getHours(); 
    return currentTime;
}
```

Comment: Syntax error questions should not be answered, I was told

Answer (score 2):

This code work:

```
function abc() {   
 var today = new Date();
 return  today.getHours(); 
}


display.log(abc())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `()` for your function.

```
function abc(){   
    var today = new Date();
    var currentTime = today.getHours(); 
    return currentTime;
}

console.log(abc())
```

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration is wrong. After the function name `()` should be used. Refer below code

```
function abc() {   
var returnString = '';
var today = new Date();
var currentTime = today.getHours(); 
return currentTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration is wrong.  Instead of

```js
function abc {
```

you need to list the parameters, even if it's an empty list, with something like this:

```js
function abc () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

You are missing `()` as others pointed out.

Second, I'm not sure what the purpose of the method is, but it can be shortened. See my `abcd()`

```
var a = abc();
var b = abcd();
console.log(a);
console.log(b);

function abc() {   
    var returnString = '';
    var today = new Date();
    var currentTime = today.getHours(); 
    return currentTime;
}

function abcd() {
  return new Date().getHours();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it further by using an arrow function as seen below:

```js
const abc = () => new Date().getHours()

console.log(abc());
```

Comment: You don't need the return statement or the curly braces if you want to keep it short. `abc = () => new Date().getHours()` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Everything was ok. You were missing parentheses in the function declaration. Instead of `function abc{...}` you should use `function abc(){...}`. And to display it you can call the function in the `console.log(abc())`